# Issue with truncating html content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my truncate function:

```
function truncate_updates(txt, cnt, opt) {
        if(updates_topic=='') {
            return truncateText(txt, cnt, opt);
        } else {
            return txt;
        }
    }

function truncateText(text, len, show_readmore) {
    if(text==''|| text==null)
        return;
    if(text.length > len) {
        if(show_readmore == 'truncate')
            text = text.substring(0, len)+'...';
        else if(show_readmore=='link')
            text = text.substring(0, len)+'<span class="cpoint circuitCol"> more</span>';
        else if(show_readmore != false)
            text = '<span act="show_trn_txt">'+text.substring(0, len)+'</span><span class="cpoint circuitCol" act="show_readmore_text"> read more</span><span act="readmore" class="display-hide">'+text+'</span>';
    }
    return text;
}
```

The HTML content breaks when i try to truncate using this function.

HTML Content:

```
<a class="ashcol">dsdsdsad sdasdasd dsdasd asdasdsa sdasdasdasd sdasdasdasd sdsadasdasd sdasdasdasd sdasdasdasd sdasdsd dssds sdsds sdsds sdsd sdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd </a><a href="http://192.168.1.41/4thambit_v6/hashtags/hashtag=fourthambit">#fourthambit</a> <a href="http://192.168.1.41/4thambit_v6/hashtags/hashtag=socialmedia">#socialmedia</a> <a href="http://192.168.1.41/4thambit_v6/hashtags/hashtag=development">#development</a> <a href="http://192.168.1.41/4thambit_v6/hashtags/hashtag=cakephp">#cakephp</a> <a href="http://192.168.1.41/4thambit_v6/hashtags/hashtag=php">#php</a>
```

Comment: do you mind using css `text-ellipsis`. Here the solution http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Does len take into consideration the length of the text you are adding to show that there's more content? ( '...' ,  'more'  )

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul tat won't do as i have multiple lines...

Comment: i did it using php... anyone looking for php way can follow this link http://alanwhipple.com/2011/05/25/php-truncate-string-preserving-html-tags-words/